# How do I create a many-to-many DB schema that also keeps an order for the items associated?

Tags: android, sql, database

Forgive me if this is fairly simple, I'm new at databases and couldn't find any answers through searching.

I'm looking to create a DB for an android app where there are a number of workouts and each workout has a number of drills. I know I need to create a joint/association table, but the problem is I also need to keep the drills in a certain order and store reps for each drill based on the workout and I'm not really sure how.

Right now I have the three basic tables outlined, but I'm not really sure how to add order and reps.

**Current tables:**

Workouts:       id, name, description

Drills:         id, name, description,

WorkoutsDrills: Workout_id, Drill_id

Missing info:   reps_for_drill, order

---

The output I'd like to get is when I pull a workout, I pull a list of drill_IDs, along with some information to put them in order. I also need to get the number of reps for each drill, but the reps are not static to the drill, they are assigned to each drill based on the workout.

Right now I just pull a list of random drills, with no reps stored. If I store the reps in the drill db, then I need a new drill for each instance of a different amount of reps.

**sample data**

I guess here's some sample data to help explain.

*Drills*

```
Name            Description
Pushups         standard pushup
Situps          standard situp
Jumping Jacks   standard jumping jack
```

*Workouts*

```
Name        Description          Drills in a workout(reps)
workout1    sample description   Pushups(10), Situps(5)
workout2    sample description2  situps(5), Jumping Jacks(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some trial and error, I figured out a solution. Ended up being pretty simple. Here are the tables and classes I used.

### Classes

---

I had two classes: Drill and Workout. The only methods they had were getter and setter methods. Below are their fields.

*Drill*

```
private String mDrillName;
private String mDrillDescription;
private int mDrillReps;
```

*Workout*

```
private String mWorkoutName;
private String mWorkoutDescription;
private ArrayList<Drill> mDrillList;
```

---

### Tables

---

I ended up going with the three tables, one for storing general info on each object and an association table for storing their relations.

*Drills*

```
INT  : _ID
TEXT : Name
TEXT : Description
```

*Workouts*

```
INT  : _ID
TEXT : Name
TEXT : Description
```

*workoutdrill*

```
INT : W_ID       //workout ID
INT : D_ID       //Drill ID
INT : orderNum   //Keeps track of the order of drills in the workout
INT : reps       //Keeps track of the number of reps to do for a drill
```

---

I haven't fully implemented the usage of the DB yet, I'll come back and put that code in here when I have. My plan to pull the info and populate a workout object, based on a workout_ID number is:

1. Query the workout table for basic info from the row and populate name and description fields of a workout object.
2. Query a associationCursor from the workouts table containing all rows that match the specific workout ID number in the W_ID column.
3. Go to first (or next) line of the associationCursor
4. Take the drill_ID number and query it from the drills table to return a drillCursor.
5. Use the two cursors to populate a new tempDrill. (name and description from drillCursor and rep from associationCursor.
6. Push this temp drill into the ArrayList of the workout.
7. Repeats steps 3-6 till associationCursor is at the end.

After that, a workout Object should be fully populated with information and usable for what ever is needed.

---

Please feel free to suggest improvements.